# How can I migrate schema and data from Access 2000 to Sql Server 2008?

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2008, migrate

I want to copy the data from an existing Access 2000 database to an existing Sql Server 2008 database.  I would prefer to have the ability to only copy some data, so that I may add constraints (like ON CASCADE DELETE) as I go.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There is a free application provided by Microsoft called [SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) 2008 for Access V4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=133B59C2-C89C-4641-BEBB-6D04476EC1BA&displaylang=en&displaylang=en):

> Microsoft SQL Server Migration
>   Assistant (SSMA) 2008 for Access is a
>   tool for migrating databases from
>   Microsoft Access to Microsoft SQL
>   Server 2008. SSMA for Access converts
>   Access database objects to SQL Server
>   database objects, loads those objects
>   into SQL Server, and then migrates
>   data from Access to SQL Server. SSMA
>   for Access supports Access 97 - Access
>   2007 databases.

Comment: Above link no longer applies, here is the latest version: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54255 - otherwise just google for "ssma download"